# Afnetworking 3.0 Migration : How to post with xml post body

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I am trying to POST some data to the server with body formatted as XML, everything works well with

```
request.HTTPBody = [self.body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
 [request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
```

Now in Afnetworking 3.0 they changed AFHTTPRequestOperation to AFHTTPSessionManager any way to do post xml data with AFHTTPSessionManager

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `AFURLSessionManager` class for this use. For that, create a `AFURLSessionManager` instance then create NSURLSessionDataTask from the manager with your `NSURLRequest` . Use that task to post your data
Eg code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = ....;
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes =  [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/xml"];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSString *fetchedXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response string: %@",fetchedXML);
 }];
[task resume];
```

**Update** 
If you are using `AFXMLParserResponseSerializer` as response serializer, then
Add this code to start xml parsing

```
NSXMLParser *xmlparser = responseObject;
[xmlparser setDelegate:self];
[xmlparser parse];
```

And implement `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods.

You can find a nice tutorial for parsing xml here - [XML Parsing with NSXMLParser](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/xmlparsing-with-nsxmlparser-tutorial)

Comment: @johnykuty : thanks for the quick response. Is it possible for   [request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]? i am getting error  for application/xml :(

Comment: getting error message "NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/xml"

Comment: please provide full error log, including error.userinfo

Comment: its fixed by adding manager.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];  and now i am getting responseObject its a NSxmlParser object how i will pick the data from it ..

Comment: @Johnykutty right now this manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes is giving error. object not found. This "acceptableContentTypes" is present is a class which we are accessing but it is not accessible

Comment: @Ali can you say what is the exact error you are getting? compile error or crash?

Comment: @Johnykutty its compile time error.. Error : "Object not found"

Comment: @Ali Sorry, I didn't get the error. In my project its compiling without any error.. Last thing, how you are importing the AFNetworking in your project, cocoa pods or copying source files inside project. And the import statement?

Comment: @Johnykutty installing thru cocoa pods and import "AFURLSessionManager.h" only

Comment: can you try #import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h> . if this is also not working, can you get a screenshot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118375/discussion-between-ali-and-johnykutty).